# It is a combination of bitwise and binary operations

Tags: python

I came across this problem,
what will be the value of `a` after the following operations?

```
a = (0100 == 0b10 ** 0x6) and ("mora" not in "thora")
```

here the first bracket is understandable, but I don't know how the second bracket works? does it check each and every letter in those two words ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

`"mora" in "thora"` checks if the whole word `mora` is in the word `thora`. For example:

```
"mora" in "thora" -> False
"ora" in "thora"  -> True, because th-ora contains the whole "ora" word
```

When `not` is added, it check if the word `mora` NOT in the word `thora`.

In your case, `("mora" not in "thora")` returns `True` because the word `thora` doesn't contain word `mora`

Answer (score 1):

```
("mora" in "thora")
```

checks whether "mora" is a substring in "thora"

so

```
("mora" not in "thora")
```

checks whether "mora" is a not substring in "thora"

Comment: thank you so much for replying fast , appreciate it sir

Answer (score 1):

The condition uses the `__contains__` method or "dunder" contains magic method. This implementation can vary depending on your types.
In this specific example, it is checking if the string `mora` is not contained in the string `thora`

Here are some other examples of this operator in the wild,

```py
Python 3.4.4 (default, Jul  9 2018, 09:26:46)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> "book" in "books"
True
>>> 1 in [1, 2, 3, 4]
True
>>> 12 in [1, 2, 3, 4]
False
>>> 'a' in {1, 2, 3}
False
>>> 'foo' in {'foo': 'bar', 'bat': 'baz'}
True
```

You can implement this function in your own class.
A comparison of the time complexity of these operations for different data types can be found [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).